# Clearing Graphics from a Window in Python

Tags: python, text, graphics, window, draw

So I'm trying to make a timed loop where different text commands appear on the screen and users have to press the key that corresponds with the text command. The problem is since the text is centered it just draws over itself until the commands are unreadable. Is there a way I can clear the window each time i want to draw text to the window? I posted my current code below

```
from Graphics import *
from Myro import timer  #used for the animation.
import random   #random starting positions and speeds

NUMBALLS = 10
WINSIZE = 500
done = 0
win = Window("GAME", WINSIZE, WINSIZE)
#win.mode = "manual"  #Trick to make the animation smoother....

space = Text((180, 250), "SPACEBAR")
space.fill = Color("blue")
space.fontSize = 30
space.xJustification = "bottom"
space.yJustification = "bottom"

up = Text((180, 250), "UP")
up.fill = Color("red")
up.fontSize = 30
up.xJustification = "bottom"
up.yJustification = "bottom"

down = Text((180, 250), "DOWN")
down.fill = Color("black")
down.fontSize = 30
down.xJustification = "bottom"
down.yJustification = "bottom"

left = Text((180, 250), "LEFT")
left.fill = Color("green")
left.fontSize = 30
left.xJustification = "bottom"
left.yJustification = "bottom"

right = Text((180, 250), "RIGHT")
right.fill = Color("orange")
right.fontSize = 30
right.xJustification = "bottom"
right.yJustification = "bottom"

shape = Rectangle((0, 500), (500, 0))
shape.fill = Color("white")


keys = (space,up,left,right,down)

def handleKeyPress(win, event):
    global done
    if ((this == 0) and (done == 0)):
        if (event.key == "space"):
            print("correct")
            done = 1
    if ((this == 1) and (done == 0)):
        if (event.key == "Up"):
            print("correct")
            done = 1
    #if ((this == 2) and (done == 0)):
     #   if (event.key == "Left"):
        #    print("correct")
         #   done = 1
    #if ((this == 3) and (done == 0)):
   #     if (event.key == "Right"):
         #   print("correct")
            done = 1
   # if ((this == 4) and (done == 0)):
     #   if (event.key == "Down"):
    #        print("correct")
      #      done = 1


for i in timer(5):
    shape.draw(win)
    this = random.randint(0,4)
    me = keys[this]
    me.draw(win)
    onKeyPress(handleKeyPress)
    print("done")

    wait(0.4)
    done = 0
```

Comment: Do you mean the "Zelle Graphics" package? I don't think there's a standard "Graphics" package included in Python dsitributions (at least I get an import error...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: Apparantly, you're using Calico graphics, which is built on IronPython not Cython and does not have access to the tkinter bindings. The underlying implementation is Gtk, not tkinter, and that's the place to look if you're trying to extend the functionality (though it looks perfectly sufficient as is). The short answer is window.clear(), I believe, in this case.

---

"Graphics" is not, as far as I know, a standard Python package. I get import errors on Python 2 and 3. However, I believe that "Zelle" graphics is a pretty standard Python learning library, and you look like you're learning, so I would guess that Graphics == Zelle Graphics

That said, I'll answer the question more generally than to that specific package, which isn't really used in canonical Python.

Graphics is built on tkinter, a very powerful low-level interface between Python and tk. The Graphics canvas is actually a tkinter Canvas instance.

Here's the effbot documentation on tkinter canvas objects:

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm

It's very clear and easy to use - you'll notice that there's

```
my_canvas.delete('all')
my_canvas.create_text(0,0,text='whatever')
```

solves your problem.

Go to the source code for Zelle graphics, it's very simple, and look at where the canvas is hidden. Then call methods directly on it. It will give you more power and be a more extensible solution, plus put you in a position to move onto the more powerful tool with ease!

Here's the code for Zelle graphics:

http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py

You'll notice that all Graphics instances have a reference to "self.canvas". It isn't even hidden (which would be indicated with "__" prefix on the variable name), so you can directly access the canvas to do whatever you want to it. In the interest of having the simplest solution too, we might note that you could also just use "setText" on a single text object instead of making multiple of them which replace each other.

Comment: I'm not sure what zelle graphics are, but for my coding class we have to use the program Calico to run our code so that's problem where the problems you were having probably came from. I'll take a look at it but we haven't been given any resources that directly comment on setText or canvases of any kind. I was given this page to reference http://calicoproject.org/Calico_Graphics#Text but I don't think it has those commands listed.

Comment: ya so Zelle graphics isn't your thing...I guess I should have just waited for you to respond to the comment. The Calico environment doesn't list it's implementation in the paper it was published under, or its documentation (which isn't even up right now), but the cached version http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:1H_HDNkR9B8J:web1.cs.brynmawr.edu/Calico_Graphics+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us implies that window.clear() will do the trick

Comment: Okay great i'll give it a try

Comment: A quick google search pulls up that Calico was actually built on IronPython, not Cython, so it doesn't even use tkinter. It's built on Gtk, if you'd like to get at the underlying implementation. I'll probably delete this answer once you get it since it isn't accurate, why don't you self-answer once you figure out what the problem was

Comment: Just wanted to come back and say it worked. I just implemented it thanks so much.